# Can you have an else statement print something and break from a loop with one line?

Tags: python-3.x

So let's say I have something like this:

```
while True:
  if x == x: print("x is equal to itself!")
  else:
    print("something's not right")
    break
```

Is there a way to condense that else statement into a single line similar to the if statement?

Comment: Any way to condense this would work. Speed doesn't matter; the number of lines does. Don't ask.

Comment: This code makes no sense because the value of `x` doesn’t change inside the loop.

Comment: @Onyambu *"x is ALWAYS equal to x"* - [Oh really?](https://tio.run/##PcoxEsIgEAXQPqf40hBqGydObuEFcGYJO@KCsJng6TGVr37lqzHL9VbqGB0rQspeZyterJuOyInwqDstE8AB51jRF5TKorPp4Ab67D5BM1gbpXAx7ryUGv1by2/SyLLZBsmKyltU4@54VvKvMX4)

Comment: @KellyBundy apart from `NAN` values

Comment: @Onyambu [Not a NAN](https://tio.run/##PY2xDoIwFEV3vuLKIk3cXAyGwcWRyb2p@oDG2sLrI@LX12KM8zn33PEtQ/D7w8gp3ZyJEW2Q9tTWBXCnDlrTpHUVyXU7GJ9t63u1UoBJZvY4GxepWND8ppUqXoN1hAvPtJq2Q6YNlhojWy9VucBG0DQbBwmwsuY3pcou5dZfi@FJ38NthA8Ctv0gpTriymQeKX0A).

Comment: @KellyBundy haha I see your point haha.

Comment: @Onyambu Maybe more interestingly, `x == x` is [three bytecode instructions](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRCEls5gLiPWAWEO9QsHWVqFCXfP/fwA), and between the two `LOAD_NAME` for `x`, the value *could* change.

Comment: @Onyambu [Example with regular ints](https://tio.run/##JY7BDsIgEETv@xXbUyEao/FiTLjqyXjpD9AWC5ECARrx6xFhLpvZzM5b943SmvPF@Zxf3q4YpRd8VmZBtTrrIw51AZCQ4RH8Zsoc/CYAZvHCSYrpTegVsGjRduQaS6baj1RaYLljmFrgL8dDqKZV3bgOonrnlYmkfz7uFR2CGrXouq7fY6IA7Q8SuV9EZJVLD6HYSCg0VGlsnIQ7hqecfw).

Comment: @Cheesy Why don't you do `while x == x: print("x is equal to itself!")` instead?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Another thread can change it.

Comment: @KellyBundy Sure, but the OP didn't say so.

Comment: this isn't my actual code, just an example but i love the discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
while True:
  if x == x: print("x is equal to itself!")
  else: print("something's not right"); break
```

<strike>Also if x ALWAYS equals x the "Else" statement will never be used.</strike>

Comment: Actually, it would be possible for x to not equal itself. If `x = decimal.Decimal('NaN')`, then the else statement would be used, because NaN will never be equal to itself.

Comment: @2pichar I see what you mean.  I'm not that advanced in coding though.

Comment: That is a rare edge case that you likely won't have, but that's why the else statement exists, right?

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Forgot semicolons are used like that in python, but this is just example code, not the real thing :)

Answer (score 0):

To build on the other answers, here is my suggestion:

```py
while True:
    if x == x: print('x is equal to itself!')
    else: print('x is nan!'); break;
```

Because in most programming languages, including python and js, NaN != NaN.